# Possible to have 100% screen width inside limited div with relative position?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, responsive-design

I wonder if it's possible to have a div **stretch to `100vw`**, while being **inside a `relative` parent div** with limited width. And in the process also not losing it's height inside the document, as it would when setting position to absolute.

Is it possible with pure css? Or do I need some jQuery / JS?

```css
body {
  background: #f0f0f0;
  text-align: center;
}

.parent {
  max-width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  background: white;
}

p {
  padding: 20px;
}

#banner {
  padding: 20px;
  background: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <p>My relative parent container,<br>with a fixed width.</p>
  <div id="banner">
    My full width banner
  </div>
  <p>...</p>
</div>
```

Anyone has any experience in getting this to work?
Any and all tips are much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use 100vw width. To correct the position, you can add `margin-left: calc(-50vw + 50%);`, which moves it half of the screen width to the left and then back 50% of its own width to the right, thereby "centering" it again, which in this case results in a full-width element:

```css
body {
  background: #f0f0f0;
  text-align: center;
}

.parent {
  max-width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  background: white;
}

p {
  padding: 20px;
}

#banner {
  padding: 20px;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  width: 100vw;
  margin-left: calc(-50vw + 50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <p>My relative parent container,<br>with a fixed width.</p>
  <div id="banner">
    My full width banner
  </div>
  <p>...</p>
</div>
```

There is one problem remaining however: As soon as the contents are longer than the window height, a horizontal scrollbar will appear. I previously brought up that problem in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58698412/5641669), but I haven't really found a solution or got a satisfying answer for it.

Comment: Aahhh... Such elegant and simple solution. Many thanks @Johannes ! :) Too bad about the horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: I read your post, interesting! I guess I will just ad `body{overflow-x: hidden}` untill a better solution is found.

Comment: Adding this codepen as additional reference: https://codepen.io/bassplayer7/pen/egZKpm. If offers a solution using some JavaScript.

Comment: @TVBZ That's a very cool patch you made there - thanks for sharing that! Although I really would like to find a CSS-only solution for this problem (which however is probably impossible), this is a great way to work around that problem.

Comment: Some credit goes to the author @bassplayer7 offcourse :) I would also prefer pure css. But for now, this will have to do :)

Answer (score 1):

I use `relative` with `margin` and `left` `right` to achieve this

```css
body {
  background: #f0f0f0;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.parent {
  max-width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  background: white;
}

p {
  padding: 20px;
}

#banner {
  padding: 20px;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  width: 100vw;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  margin-left: -50vw;
  margin-right: -50vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <p>My relative parent container,<br>with a fixed width.</p>
  <div id="banner">
    My full width banner
  </div>
  <p>...</p>
</div>
```

[Reference](https://css-tricks.com/full-width-containers-limited-width-parents/)

Comment: That's also an interesting and elegant approach. It has the same results as  Johannes his example. And you hide horizontal scrollbar by setting `overflow-x: hidden`? Or do you have any other suggestions for that?

Comment: @TVBZ Yes I agree, As `body` and `HTML` dont need to scroll