# Why do i keep getting horizontal scrollbar, when i set margin and padding as 0 in the body element?

Tags: html, css

So I'm practicing my html and CSS trying to remake the google homepage however I keep getting horizontal scrollbar when i set the width of any element to 100%. Note I have set default margin and padding to zero in the body tag. Here's the html:

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.navbar{
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  margin: 5px;
}

a:hover{
  opacity: 70%;
}

.main-content{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.logo{
  width: 30%;
  height: 10vw;
}

.logo img{
  width: 100%;
  height:100%;
}

.form{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

footer{
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  bottom: 0;
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Google</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
  <nav class="navbar">
    <a href="#">Gmail</a>
    <a href="#">Images</a>
    <a href="#"></a>
    <a href="#"></a>
  </nav>
  <main class="main-content">
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="1.png">
    </div>
    <div class="form">
      <input type="text" name="">
      <div class="btn">
        <button>Google Search</button>
        <button>I'm Feeling Lucky</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
  <footer>
    <div>
      <a href="">Advertising</a>
      <a href="">Business</a>
      <a href="">About</a>
      <a href="">How it works</a>
    </div>
    <div>
    <a href="">Privacy</a>
    <a href="">Terms</a>
    <a href="">Settings</a>
    </div>
  </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Please note I'm a beginner and the project is still incomplete.

Comment: Does your `html` tag have 0 padding and margin? Make sure your elements that are set to `width: 100%` also aren't taking up any space, use the CSS inspector in your browser when you open "Inspect Element" to see the element properties and why it takes up more than the full space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `main-content` element is set to `width: 100vw`. This does not take into account the vertical scroll bar on the side, so it is too wide. To solve this, use `width: 100%` instead.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the `width: 100vw` for `.main-content`: There is a vertical scrollbar, but `100vw` means the *complete* width of the window *including*  the vertical scrollbar. But that doesn't fit into the visible part *left of* the scrollbar - that's why the horizontal scrollbar appears - I know, that's strange...

But you can solve it by using `width: 100%` for that element, instead of 100vw.

I had a similar problem some time ago - see this question of mine to read about it in more detail: [Problem using vw units when a vertical scrollbar appears (full-width elements in WordPress)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58698412/5641669)